# Any way to pass data from a HTML to a Java application?

Tags: java, html, selenium, webdriver

I have a JavaScript code embedded in a Java method to retrieve properties of any element clicked upon in a web page. 
That is, I navigate to a specific URL by creating an instance of Selenium WebDriver from my Java application and click on an object in the page that gets loaded. After the single click on the object, a HTML page opens listing the name, type, id, class name etc. associated to that object as a radio button group. I select one option from the list and click on OK. What I wanted to know is, can I push the selected data from the HTML back onto my Java application on the click event on the HTML?

Any help appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: Please post what you tried

Comment: Question is not clear; describe what you have tried and what is exact problem you facing.

Comment: I think, what you are trying can be achieved. In Selenium, it is possible to get the all DOM objects rendered by the browser to java via webdriver. Hence I guess you need to add logic to check if the element you are looking has been selected through xpath or csspath in java.

Answer (score 0):

> WebElement interface of selenium Webdriver gives a method
>   getAttribute which provides value of a given attribute of the desired html element.

I hope this method is what you are looking for.

**USAGE:**

```
String field_value; 
field_value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath Locator")).getAttribute("attribute name")
```

The information which you want to get should be in any of the attribute associated to that element.

Similarly if you want all attributes associated with the element in one go you can use something like this :

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].attributes);", element);
```

The above will give you a comma separated list of all attributes on which you can apply your coding logic to separate them and get the corresponding values using loops.